# AspectJ plugin in Android Studio error messages not clickable

Tags: android, android-studio, aspectj

I am using [this](https://github.com/uPhyca/gradle-android-aspectj-plugin) plugin for AspectJ support in my android project.

When I am making syntax errors , such as missing semicolon , I expect to see **clickable** error in messages log after I try to build the project.
Something like this :

> ...\designlibdemo\MainActivity.java
>   Error:(89, 63) error: ';' expected

When I click on the error line , it takes me to the class and the line where the error is occurred.

But now when I am using aspectJ plugin , I only see the error description , which is actually **not clickable** , and I cannot follow the error to the code.
Looks like this :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileProductionDebugAspectj'.
>   Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements

Does anyone know how to make it clickable , so it will take me to the error line ?

Comment: Just a thought: Maybe you can ask on the plugin's mailing list or, if you are sure that it is a missing feature or a bug, open a ticket in order to get it fixed. Your description does not read like it is a configuration problem which you could fix by yourself.

Comment: You are right , I should request the feature. But before I do , just want to make sure that I am not missing some configuration. I didn't see others complain on that issue . Even though it is reproducable on multiple machines and even different OS (Mac , Windows , Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

According to author the issue is now fixed :)
https://github.com/uPhyca/gradle-android-aspectj-plugin/issues/26